# staticContent ClientCache Setting

Tags: .net, iis, web-config

I've added the following to my web.config to enable 14 day caching of images.

```
  <location path="Images">
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMaxAge="14.00:00:00" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

When viewing in chrome using the F12 tools I can see that the browser still seems to request the image from the server when I refresh. It's getting a 304 so no downloading it again, but still seems like a wasted trip per image on page refresh etc.

Is this the correct behaviour or should it as I had expect just pull from cache based on the header it has for the file?

Answer (score 0):

Cache control is server-side, not client-side.  So the browser still has to ask the server for the file and get the `304` to know that it should use its cached copy.

Consider in the following HTML (which would be exactly the same whether or not the image is set to return from cache), how does the browser know whether to download the image or use cached version?

```
<img src="somefile.jpg" />
```

The client doesn't know, because it's not like the server sets some sort of `cache-image="true"` attribute on the `img` tag rendered to the browser.

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense to me. From what I understand, it's NOT simply server side. When the browser first requests somefile.jpg, it will receive it with headers that specify when the cached version of it will expire. From then on, the browser knows EXACTLY when it expires, and doesn't have to contact the server again at all (until that specified expiration). It simply goes to the local cache on the client computer.